# Need help with the limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need help on a question from my homework, which asks me to find the limit of the sequence as n approaches infinity of

$$a_n = \frac{\cos^2 n}{2^n}$$

Thanks

Comment: Numerator bounded. What does the denominator tend to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Notice $$\frac{-1}{2^n} \leq\frac{\cos^2 n}{ 2^n} \leq \frac{1}{2^n} $$ for all $n$. Now use Squeeze Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **sandwich theorem** for the sequence to obtain the result of limit is $0$.

See here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpbxFJphGyg

Answer (score 0):

divide the problem:
it's $a_n = b_n / c_n $ 
where $b_n = cos^2(n)$ and $c_n=2^n$.
what are the limits as $n\rightarrow \infty$ of $b_n$ and $c_n$?

Comment: The limit of $b_n$ does not exist.